# How change status of toggle button?

Tags: java, android

I have a toggle button to turn on and off wireless. It works fine. But, I want when I enter my app, if wireless is already on, my toggle button to be on as well. Now it's not. Something is not right. Here's my code.

```
WifiManager WifiMan;
ToggleButton WiFi, GPRS;

    WiFi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  //Ukljucuje WiFi

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if(WifiMan.isWifiEnabled())
                    {
                        WiFi.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                    else{
                        WiFi.setEnabled(false);
                    }

                    try
                      {
                        if (((ToggleButton)v).isChecked())
                        SwarmPopup.this.WifiMan.setWifiEnabled(true);
                        else
                            SwarmPopup.this.WifiMan.setWifiEnabled(false);
                      }
                    catch (Exception localException)
                      {
                        Log.e("SwarmPopup", "error on WiFi listerner: " + localException.getMessage(), localException);
                      }
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: You should consider following the [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) for naming variables. These are also Android standards, and they dictate that variables (such as WiFiMan and your WiFi ToggleButton) be lowerCamelCase. UpperCamelCase is typically reserved for class names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `WifiMan` is a WifiManager, then use:

```
WiFi.setChecked(WifiMan.isWifiEnabled());
```

Also please read about [Java naming convention](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm) which states that variables names should start with lowercase letters.

---

Lastly, code like this:

```
if(WifiMan.isWifiEnabled())
{
    WiFi.setEnabled(true);
}
else{
    WiFi.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Can be simplified to:

```
WiFi.setEnabled(WifiMan.isWifiEnabled());
```

Answer (score 2):

If that is *all* of your code (I doubt it is), then the problem is that you are only checking for WiFi status (and your toggle status) when the toggle is clicked.

If you add a check for `WiFiMan.isWifiEnabled()` in your Activity's `onCreate()`, you can easily set the toggle's status when the Activity is created.

Comment: An upvote from me, since we posted the same advice at the same time, twice. Once for code, a second time for naming convention.